# EFI system partition cannot be of type ntfs, EFI system must be mounted on one of /boot/efi

Tags: linux, centos, partition, dual-boot

I have tried to install CentOS alongside windows 10 and for this I created some unallocated space for the CentOS.

While proceeding with installation of CentOS I came to stage of partition and then I created three partitions, they are:

1. swap  (8GB)
2. /     (10GB)      -->standard partition
3. /home (45 GB)     -->standard partition

As soon as I click the done button I got the error:

> EFI system partition cannot be of type ntfs, EFI system must be
>   mounted on one of /boot/efi

what should I do now to install the OS successfully?

Comment: Use FAT32, for ESP.

Comment: That's odd. In summary, the UEFI specification states the ESP (EFI system partition) must be FAT32. Within the CentOS liveCD/installer, open a terminal and run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `findmnt`. Add the output of those commands to you question.

Comment: It would be interesting to find out why CentOS detected this anomaly. As the machine already has Windows installed, you should be careful and not create a new EFI system partition because that may break Windows. There should be only one EFI system partition on the disk that is shared by all operating systems. Is the ESP really formatted as NTFS, or maybe just the type is wrong in the partition table? Theoretically, the manufacturer could have included an NTFS driver in the firmware, which would make it possible to use NTFS on the ESP.

Comment: @JohanMyréen i don't understand

Comment: To boot your computer using Linux or Windows you need a (and only one) EFI system partition (ESP). The ESP is like an extension to the firmware ("BIOS"), and it is where bootloaders are installed. There should have been an ESP on your machine from day one since the machine has Windows on it. The ESP should also be formatted so that it contains a FAT32 file system. If you haven't done anything to the existing ESP and it really is formatted as NTFS, then you have a non-standard machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating partition `/boot/efi` (EFI partition NOT standard partition) besides root,home and swap, resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! That solve my problem installing Fedora 32 on Thinkpad T490s